how to fix invalid escape sequence
I'm new to Java programming.
I have below string which has one variable in that
("{\r\n" + "  \"tenant\": \"https://example.com/login\"\r\n" + "}")

instead of example.com/login, I need to put variable url in that, but I don't know how to format the string with proper escaping.
Below is the error

Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'
\\ )

I have gone through many posts still no luck.
"{\r\n :" "\tenant\:" + url + "\r\n" + "}"")

Above is not working. How can I fix this? url is the variable which contains the string example.com.

The string you give compiles for me.

What really are you trying to achieve? Are you actually trying to produce a JSON string? If so, why not just use a library to do that?

"i need to put variable url in that". Ok. How about you do that and show your attempt? Showing code that works is no use to anyone.

please see update .

using the value of the variable url instead of example.com/login would be something like "{\r\n" + "  \"tenant\": \"https://" + url +  "\"\r\n" + "}"... despite I would prefer using a formatter like String.format() (commented before the question was updated...)

why do you change "{\r\n" + "  \"tenant into "{\r\n :" "\tenant; and tenant\": into tenant\:"  ??? (having just two strings without + is not valid in Java, neither is \:)

Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. As far as I'm aware, the error is not a compilation error of Java, so it's likely an error of whatever receives your resulting string.

e.g. String.format("{\r\n  \"tenant\": \"%s\"\r\n}", url), or using the system default newlines, if appropriate: String.format("{%n  \"tenant\": \"%s\"%n}", url) -- Note: better use some library to properly create JSON (if that is the case)

thanks all . it worked . thanks everyone for all comments and support

Like this:
("{\r\n" + "  \"tenant\": \"" + url + "\"\r\n" + "}")

